# place text on margin of facet_wrap ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot below of the data in `foo`, how can put the text "50%" on the right margin at the median value of each facet? I imagine it's a a `geom_text` with `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` but I don't know how to incorporate the facets.

```
foo <- data.frame(x=rep(1:50,times=2),y=c(rnorm(50,mean=2),rnorm(50,mean=4)),
                                          z=rep(c("A","B"),each=50))
bar <- foo %>% group_by(z) %>% summarise(med=median(y))

ggplot(foo,aes(x,y,color=z)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(data=bar,aes(yintercept = med,col=z)) +
  facet_wrap(z~.,ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,3,1,1), "lines"))
# place "50%" in right margin at bar$med for each facet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding an annotation to the plot margins you could use the *secondary axis trick* which means to add your annotation via a secondary axis. As you want to place the annotation at different positions I use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` from the `ggh4x` package which allows to individually set the `breaks` for each facet. Doing so requires to set `scales = "free_y"` in `facet_wrap` and as this will change the limits, I use the `limits` argument to get the same limits for each facet:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

set.seed(123)

scale_dup <- function(x) {
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = bar[bar$z == x, "med", drop = TRUE],
      labels = "50%"
    ), limits = range(foo$y)
  )
}

ggplot(foo, aes(x, y, color = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(data = bar, aes(yintercept = med, col = z)) +
  facet_wrap(z ~ ., ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      z == "A" ~ scale_dup("A"),
      z == "B" ~ scale_dup("B")
    )
  )
```

[image]