# control per-axis ggplot2 clipping

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, clipping

This is an extension beyond a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63550588/3358272), where the goal was to set different limits for each facet. The code from that question is stored in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/6057f7995c117bb787495dc14a228d5d), and has been in production since.

A quick demo with sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x = seq(0,1,len=101), y = cumsum(runif(101,-1,1)), z=sample(1:3, size=101, replace=TRUE))
dat$y <- dat$y * dat$z
dat$y[50] <- 99
dat$z[50] <- 2L
lims <- data.frame(z=1:3, ymin=0, ymax=c(10,25,30))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(z ~ ., switch="both", scales="free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = "on")
```

[image: ggplot2 with per-facet limits]

I now have a need to add `geom_label`s to the right side of the plot, *outside* of plot region. *Edit*: multiple labels per facet, with colors (whose order is inconsistent between facets). Doing this is relatively straight-forward: place the label at the edge of the screen, extend the theme's `plot.margin`, and turn off clipping. Unfortunately, as you might imagine with the two excursions in facets `2` and `3`, disabling clipping is a concern.

```r
summ <- aggregate(y ~ z, dat, FUN = function(z) c(lo=mean(z)-3, hi=mean(z)+3)) |>
  do.call(data.frame, args = _) |>
  reshape2::melt("z", variable.name = "ign", value.name = "y") |>
  transform(lbl = sprintf("%0.03f", y)) |>
  transform(fill = factor(ave(z, z, FUN = function(ign) sample(seq_along(ign)))))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(z ~ ., switch="both", scales="free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(x = 1, aes(y = y, label = lbl, fill = fill), data = summ, hjust = -0.1) +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.65 * max(nchar(summ$lbl)), 0.5, 0.5), "char")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")
```

[image: ggplot2 with side labels and broken clipping]

I supposed there are three possible ways to resolve this:

1. Find another way to add the labels on the right side that does not require disabling clipping. To be clear, theming (background, axis lines/ticks/labels, etc) should not be affected by this. There are many other components to these plots here, I need the plot region to "stop" cleanly before the labels begin.
2. Find a way to clip on the `y` axis and not the `x`. In this case I have "strict" control over the x-values so am not as concerned about running amuck on either the left or right side.
3. Incorporate `oob` use (e.g., `scales::oob_squish`) into the `ggproto` use within `coord_cartesian_panels`.
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I suppose there are reasons not to consider plotting the labels separately & combining the results together using one of the usual suspects such as cowplot, patchwork, etc.)*

I wrote a modified version of `FacetGrid` that could accept separate clipping instructions for each layer. Combine that with specifying `clip = c("on", "off")` in `coord_cartesian_panels` seems to work.

Note: having a legend positioned to the right of the plot (i.e. default legend position) will mess up the appearance, but I'd consider that an intrinsic part of the way ggplot grobs are laid out. Since the use case here doesn't place a legend on the right, I assume it's not a key requirement for now.

Demonstration with same use case in the question:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid2(z ~ ., switch="both", scales="free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(x = 1, aes(y = y, label = lbl, fill = fill), data = summ, hjust = -0.1) +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = c("on", "off")) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.65 * max(nchar(summ$lbl)), 0.5, 0.5), "char")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")
```

[image: result]

Further demonstration for layer-specific clipping by adding another geom layer, but this one clipped at the edge:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid2(z ~ ., switch="both", scales="free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(x = 1, aes(y = y, label = lbl, fill = fill), data = summ, hjust = -0.1) +
  geom_label(x = 1, aes(y = y-5, label = lbl, fill = fill), data = summ, hjust = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = c("on", "off", "on")) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.65 * max(nchar(summ$lbl)), 0.5, 0.5), "char")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")
```

[image: result2]

Code for `facet_grid2` / `FacetGrid2` (change from original is mainly a chunk in the middle of the latter's `draw_panels` function, to allow separate clipping options for different geom layers; everything else is inherited directly from my current version of ggplot2, which is 3.4.2):

```
library(rlang)

FacetGrid2 <- ggproto(
  "FacetGrid2", ggplot2::FacetGrid,
  draw_panels = function(panels, layout, x_scales, y_scales, ranges, coord, data, theme, params) {
    if ((params$free$x || params$free$y) && !coord$is_free()) {
      cli::cli_abort("{.fn {snake_class(coord)}} doesn't support free scales")
    }
    
    cols <- which(layout$ROW == 1)
    rows <- which(layout$COL == 1)
    axes <- render_axes(ranges[cols], ranges[rows], coord, theme, transpose = TRUE)
    
    col_vars <- ggplot2:::unique0(layout[names(params$cols)])
    row_vars <- ggplot2:::unique0(layout[names(params$rows)])
    # Adding labels metadata, useful for labellers
    attr(col_vars, "type") <- "cols"
    attr(col_vars, "facet") <- "grid"
    attr(row_vars, "type") <- "rows"
    attr(row_vars, "facet") <- "grid"
    strips <- render_strips(col_vars, row_vars, params$labeller, theme)
    
    aspect_ratio <- theme$aspect.ratio
    if (!is.null(aspect_ratio) && (params$space_free$x || params$space_free$y)) {
      cli::cli_abort("Free scales cannot be mixed with a fixed aspect ratio")
    }
    if (is.null(aspect_ratio) && !params$free$x && !params$free$y) {
      aspect_ratio <- coord$aspect(ranges[[1]])
    }
    if (is.null(aspect_ratio)) {
      aspect_ratio <- 1
      respect <- FALSE
    } else {
      respect <- TRUE
    }
    ncol <- max(layout$COL)
    nrow <- max(layout$ROW)
    
    if (params$space_free$x) {
      ps <- layout$PANEL[layout$ROW == 1]
      widths <- vapply(ps, function(i) diff(ranges[[i]]$x.range), numeric(1))
      panel_widths <- unit(widths, "null")
    } else {
      panel_widths <- rep(unit(1, "null"), ncol)
    }
    if (params$space_free$y) {
      ps <- layout$PANEL[layout$COL == 1]
      heights <- vapply(ps, function(i) diff(ranges[[i]]$y.range), numeric(1))
      panel_heights <- unit(heights, "null")
    } else {
      panel_heights <- rep(unit(1 * abs(aspect_ratio), "null"), nrow)
    }
    
    # changes from here onwards    
    relevant.panel.children <- with(panels[[1]],
                                    which(!grepl("grill|NULL|zeroGrob", childrenOrder)))
    if(length(coord$clip) == 1) {
      panel.layer.grouping <- list(seq_along(panels[[1]]$childrenOrder))
    } else if (length(coord$clip) == length(relevant.panel.children)) {
      panel.layer.grouping <- lapply(relevant.panel.children, function(n) n)
      panel.layer.grouping[[1]] <- seq_len(panel.layer.grouping[[1]])
      panel.layer.grouping[[length(relevant.panel.children)]] <- seq(panel.layer.grouping[[length(relevant.panel.children)]],
                                                                     length(panels[[1]]$childrenOrder))
    } else {
      message("Clipping instruction cannot be matched unambiguously to layers.")
      break()
    }

    by.layer.clip.info <- coord$clip
    panel_table <- vector("list", length = length(by.layer.clip.info))

    for(i in seq_along(by.layer.clip.info)) {
      panels_by_layer <- lapply(panels, 
                                function(p) p$children[panel.layer.grouping[[i]]])
      panel_table_by_layer <- matrix(panels_by_layer, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = TRUE)

      panel_table_by_layer <- gtable::gtable_matrix(paste("layout", i, sep = "-"), panel_table_by_layer,
                                                    panel_widths, panel_heights, respect = respect, 
                                                    clip = by.layer.clip.info[[i]], 
                                                    z = matrix(1, ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow))
      panel_table[[i]] <- panel_table_by_layer
    }

    panel_table_combined <- panel_table[[1]]
    if(length(by.layer.clip.info) > 1) {
      for(i in seq(2, length(by.layer.clip.info))) {
        for(j in seq_len(nrow(panel_table[[i]]))) {
          grob.dimensions <- panel_table[[i]]$layout[j, ]
          panel_table_combined <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table_combined,
                                                          list(panel_table[[i]]$grobs[[j]]),
                                                          t = grob.dimensions[["t"]],
                                                          l = grob.dimensions[["l"]],
                                                          b = grob.dimensions[["b"]],
                                                          r = grob.dimensions[["r"]],
                                                          z = grob.dimensions[["z"]],
                                                          clip = grob.dimensions[["clip"]],
                                                          name = grob.dimensions[["name"]])
        }
      }
    }
    panel_table <- panel_table_combined

    layout.names <- paste0('panel-', rep(seq_len(nrow), ncol), '-', rep(seq_len(ncol), each = nrow))
    if(length(layout.names) == nrow(panel_table$layout)) {
      panel_table$layout$name <- layout.names
    } else {
      panel_table$layout$name <- paste(rep(layout.names, times = length(by.layer.clip.info)),
                                       rep(seq_along(by.layer.clip.info), each = length(layout.names)),
                                       sep = "-")
    }

    # no changes after this point
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_col_space(panel_table,
                                        theme$panel.spacing.x %||% theme$panel.spacing)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_row_space(panel_table,
                                        theme$panel.spacing.y %||% theme$panel.spacing)
    
    # Add axes
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(axes$x$top),     0)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(axes$x$bottom), -1)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(axes$y$left),     0)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(axes$y$right),   -1)
    panel_pos_col <- panel_cols(panel_table)
    panel_pos_rows <- panel_rows(panel_table)
    
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$x$top, 1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "off", name = paste0("axis-t-", seq_along(axes$x$top)), z = 3)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$x$bottom, -1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "off", name = paste0("axis-b-", seq_along(axes$x$bottom)), z = 3)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 1, clip = "off", name = paste0("axis-l-", seq_along(axes$y$left)), z = 3)
    panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, axes$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -1, clip = "off", name = paste0("axis-r-", seq_along(axes$y$right)), z= 3)
    
    # Add strips
    switch_x <- !is.null(params$switch) && params$switch %in% c("both", "x")
    switch_y <- !is.null(params$switch) && params$switch %in% c("both", "y")
    inside_x <- (theme$strip.placement.x %||% theme$strip.placement %||% "inside") == "inside"
    inside_y <- (theme$strip.placement.y %||% theme$strip.placement %||% "inside") == "inside"
    strip_padding <- grid::convertUnit(theme$strip.switch.pad.grid, "cm")
    panel_pos_col <- panel_cols(panel_table)
    if (switch_x) {
      if (!is.null(strips$x$bottom)) {
        if (inside_x || all(vapply(axes$x$bottom, is.zero, logical(1)))) {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$bottom), -2)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$bottom, -2, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-b-", seq_along(strips$x$bottom)), z = 2)
        } else {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, strip_padding, -1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$bottom), -1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$bottom, -1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-b-", seq_along(strips$x$bottom)), z = 2)
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (!is.null(strips$x$top)) {
        if (inside_x || all(vapply(axes$x$top, is.zero, logical(1)))) {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$top), 1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$top, 2, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-t-", seq_along(strips$x$top)), z = 2)
        } else {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, strip_padding, 0)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_rows(panel_table, max_height(strips$x$top), 0)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$x$top, 1, panel_pos_col$l, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-t-", seq_along(strips$x$top)), z = 2)
        }
      }
    }
    panel_pos_rows <- panel_rows(panel_table)
    if (switch_y) {
      if (!is.null(strips$y$left)) {
        if (inside_y || all(vapply(axes$y$left, is.zero, logical(1)))) {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$left), 1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 2, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-l-", seq_along(strips$y$left)), z = 2)
        } else {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, strip_padding, 0)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$left), 0)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$left, panel_pos_rows$t, 1, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-l-", seq_along(strips$y$left)), z = 2)
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (!is.null(strips$y$right)) {
        if (inside_y || all(vapply(axes$y$right, is.zero, logical(1)))) {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$right), -2)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -2, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-r-", seq_along(strips$y$right)), z = 2)
        } else {
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, strip_padding, -1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(panel_table, max_width(strips$y$right), -1)
          panel_table <- gtable::gtable_add_grob(panel_table, strips$y$right, panel_pos_rows$t, -1, clip = "on", name = paste0("strip-r-", seq_along(strips$y$right)), z = 2)
        }
      }
    }
    panel_table
  }
)

# only change from facet_grid is the use of FacetGrid2 instead of FacetGrid
facet_grid2 <- function (rows = NULL, cols = NULL, scales = "fixed", space = "fixed", 
                         shrink = TRUE, labeller = "label_value", as.table = TRUE, 
                         switch = NULL, drop = TRUE, margins = FALSE, facets = lifecycle::deprecated()) {
  if (lifecycle::is_present(facets)) {
    deprecate_warn0("2.2.0", "facet_grid(facets)", "facet_grid(rows)")
    rows <- facets
  }
  if (is.logical(cols)) {
    margins <- cols
    cols <- NULL
  }
  scales <- arg_match0(scales %||% "fixed", c("fixed", "free_x", 
                                              "free_y", "free"))
  free <- list(x = any(scales %in% c("free_x", "free")), y = any(scales %in% 
                                                                   c("free_y", "free")))
  space <- arg_match0(space %||% "fixed", c("fixed", "free_x", 
                                            "free_y", "free"))
  space_free <- list(x = any(space %in% c("free_x", "free")), 
                     y = any(space %in% c("free_y", "free")))
  if (!is.null(switch) && !switch %in% c("both", "x", "y")) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.arg switch} must be either {.val both}, {.val x}, or {.val y}")
  }
  facets_list <- ggplot2:::grid_as_facets_list(rows, cols)
  labeller <- ggplot2:::check_labeller(labeller)
  ggproto(NULL, FacetGrid2, shrink = shrink, 
          params = list(rows = facets_list$rows, 
                        cols = facets_list$cols, margins = margins, free = free, 
                        space_free = space_free, labeller = labeller, as.table = as.table, 
                        switch = switch, drop = drop))
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tested this for other use cases because I haven't had a need for it, so... caveat emptor. :)

Comment: Your point about using cowplot/patchwork for combining the labels is a novel approach; I've had really good success in the past with patchwork on more traditional things, I had not considered combining more complex faceted plots. That's a good idea as well!

Comment: Your use of `clip = c("on", "off", "on")` is a little confusing: if these are to be assigned to the respective panels (order matters), then I would expect at least one of the plots to have a clipping problem. The only way that makes sense in my head is if the `"off"` corresponds to `z == 1`, but I don't see how that would be inferred based on the order of factors. Can you explain how length-2 in your first code block and length-3 in your second is intended to work?

Comment: The multiple `clip = c(..)` is for different geom layers, not facet panels, so in this case clipping is on for the geom_line & 2nd geom_label layers, but off for the 1st geom_label layer. Values for `z` don't come into it.

Comment: ahhh, I misread your explanation before, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76049817/12993861) one option which does not require to disable clipping would be to use the *secondary axis trick* to add your labels via a duplicated axis. To set the breaks and labels individually per facet I draw on `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` and use `ggtext::element_markdown` for the `geom_label` look:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
library(ggtext)

scale_dup <- function(x) {
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = summ[summ$z == x, "y", drop = TRUE],
      labels = summ[summ$z == x, "lbl", drop = TRUE]
    )
  )
}

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(z ~ ., switch = "both", scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = "on") +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y.right = ggtext::element_markdown(
      size = 12,
      linewidth = .25,
      linetype = 1,
      r = unit(.25, "lines"),
      padding = unit(2, "pt")
    )
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      z == "1" ~ scale_dup(1),
      z == "2" ~ scale_dup(2),
      z == "3" ~ scale_dup(3)
    )
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Using the updated `summ` dataset, multiple labels are easily achieved. But unfortunately `ggtext` does not support the CSS property `background-color` so having different `fill` colors is not that easy to achieve. Of course could we pass a vector of colors to the `fill=` argument of `element_markdown` but that will only for work for some limited cases, i.e. we can't set the `fill` color individually for each panel.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  facet_grid(z ~ ., switch = "both", scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian_panels(panel_limits = lims, clip = "on") +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y.right = ggtext::element_markdown(
      size = 12,
      linewidth = .25,
      linetype = 1,
      r = unit(.25, "lines"),
      padding = unit(2, "pt"),
      fill = scales::hue_pal()(2)
    )
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      z == "1" ~ scale_dup(1),
      z == "2" ~ scale_dup(2),
      z == "3" ~ scale_dup(3)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting direction, thank you stefan! As always, there's just a little bit more: the right-side labels have background colors (`fill=` works), and there are multiple labels per facet, and each has its own color. I'll adapt the question to better reflect this. Since the order of colors in the labels is variable, I don't know if `element_markdown` will easily support it.

Comment: I edited my question to depict what I was talking about. I'm really intrigued by the use of `ggh4x`/`ggtext` here, a very promising direction. Thank you again!

Comment: Multiple labels are easily achieved. But you are right, while text colors are easily achieved, `ggtext` does not support the CSS property `background-color`. What a shame. :D Of course could we pass a vector of colors to the `fill` argument of `element_markdown` but that throws a bunch of warnings. :)

Comment: For completeness I just made an edit to account for multiple labels and limited support of `fill` colors. (:

Comment: I really appreciate the elegance of your approach @stefan, but unfortunately the background color (I should have stated in the first draft of the question) is a hard requirement (by the client). In fact, I _prefer_ this to what we're currently doing, as it seems more ggplot2-canonical, but the bg-fill is a hard requirement. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: I really appreciate this novel approach! Alas, I can only accept one ...